# Trying to limit my results and sort my data, from MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and Node.JS, I am trying to get data out of my MongoDB and show into my html page  which I have working with the below code however this just brings back ALL entries in no particular order:

**server.js**

```
// This is for getting the list of all players from my DB
app.get("/getPlayers", function(request, response) {
    db.getPlayers().then(function(players){
        console.log(players);
        response.send(players);
    });
});
```

**leadership.html**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.get("http://localhost:9000/getPlayers", {}, function (res) {
        let data = res;
        console.log(res);

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let name = data[i].name;
            let score = data[i].score;

            console.log(data[i].name);


            $("#leadership").append("<tr><td class=\"name\">"
                + data[i].name + "</td><td class=\"score\">" 
                + data[i].score + "</td></tr>");
         }
     });
});
</script>
```

After looking at W3 Schools I tried to alter the code to this:

```
db.getPlayers().sort().limit(10).then(function(players)
```

However my Chrome console brings back an `internal server error 500`. Can someone point out how I can sort by LARGEST NUMBER first, then LIMIT the results to say 10? Within the database there is a collection called players, which holds **name** and **score**

**db.js**

```
var Player = mongoose.model("Player", {name: String, score: Number}); 

    module.exports.Player = Player;
```

Comment: What field are you sorting on?

Comment: "my Chrome console brings back an internal server error 500" - what does your server log say?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It says `Reference error: score is not defined`

Comment: @prasad_ I need to sort on the score field and then have highest at the top, and then limit those results to say 10?

Comment: See this [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#combine-cursor-methods).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_ would those lines go within my server.js code or on the front end?

Comment: That is server code. You need to specify _what field you are sorting on_ in the `sort`. The definition of [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) used with `find`.

Comment: @K.Haydock but `score` is not mentioned in your server-side code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Little lost, yes, I thought if I used the getPlayers() this would get all the data that is held inside of players collection? i.e. name and scores?

Comment: @K.Haydock db.getPlayers() that line is wrong , Please share Schemas of players model

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar added in the question for you above :)

Comment: Please use that code
@K.Haydock Player.find().limit(10).then(function(players){
        console.log(players);
        response.send(players);
    });

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar which line should this be instead of or in addition too? :)

Comment: db.getPlayers().then(function(players){
        console.log(players);
        response.send(players);
    });    that code remove and use that code Player.find().limit(10).then(function(players){ console.log(players); response.send(players); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.
Order, sort and limit can be passed from front end or change default values after : mark.

Players is imported model, you can do it this way or use method in the model itself.

```js
app.post('/api/players',(req,res)=>{

    let order = req.body.order ? req.body.order : "-1";
    let sortBy = req.body.sortBy ? req.body.sortBy : "_id";
    let limit = req.body.limit ? parseInt(req.body.limit) : 100;      

    Players.
    find().
    sort([[sortBy,order]]).
    limit(limit).
    exec((err,players)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        res.status(200).json({
            size: players.length,
            players
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Can be passed, but shouldn't (not in this unchecked manner, at least). With this, you yourself are opening the app for a DoS attack.